# UITableView separator gone when using viewForFooterInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

`UITableView` showing separator even there is no rows. But when I use `viewForFooterInSection` the separator is gone. I want it to keep showing up. What should I do ?

[image]

Here is my code when I add footer in it :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"s"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row + 1];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    return cell;
}

// -------------------------- footer code start here --------------------------

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 40;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40)];
    title.text = @"footer here";
    title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [view addSubview:title];

    return view;
}
```

Comment: You have to maintain the height of tableview by adding the empthy array so that when you add footer it doesnt comes up or just drop the footer and add a new UIView as footer at bottom will be best option!

Comment: I have try adding `UIView` as footer by dropping it in `UITableView` in storyboard and the result is separator didn't showing up yet.

Comment: How do you set frame for tableview? You have to maintain height of tableview.

Comment: just short the tableview size and add a view, do this programatically in viewdidload and i think you will be fine

Comment: height of tableview is same as device height (I use autolayout). what should I do to make separator keep showing up ?

Answer (score 0):

this github project may give you some advices:
[CLTableWithFooterViewController](https://github.com/chrisledet/CLTableWithFooterViewController)
 Of course need some change if you would like the footer always display on the screen even if with a lot of cells.

Answer (score 0):

remove `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

and `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

use this code to keep the footer down (but always visible) and keep the separator:

```
@implementation tableView {

__weak UIView *_staticView;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

UIView *staticView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.bounds.size.height-50, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 50)];
staticView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
//add other code for UILabel here

[self.tableView addSubview:staticView];
_staticView = staticView;
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 50, 0);
} 

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
_staticView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
// this is needed to prevent cells from being displayed above our static view
[self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:_staticView];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just have a single section,right? Before you using viewForFooterInSection,it just fills blank cells all the way down.But when you call viewForFooterInSection,tableview will put a footer at the end of the section.Since you don't have the second section,it stops draw any cells.So you can make a blank second section,it will fill blank cells to the second section.